# keeping same height of row for DT table in output

Tags: r, dt

I want to set the height of row constant or fixed for DT table output. for the table below you can see difference in height of rows.

so the scenario is when the number of character increases for eg second row in this case in first col then height should get adjust as same for all rows.

```
df <- data.frame(`quote` = c("the trader belongs to","trader have long ralationship withthe same market with my opinion on thaw its implemented mmnnhhh sdfghj fghj kjhgf tyui cvbnm",
                             "types of trads happens everytime when market slow","trades have leverage with",
                             "market is continious with the same platform trades"),
                 `share`= c(43,65,92,23,73),
                 `times` = c(86,98,55,12,08),
                 `parts`=c(4,7,4,8,3))


df<-datatable(df,
              options = list(columnDefs = 
                               list(list(className = 'dt-center', 
                                         targets = "_all"))),rownames = FALSE)
df
```

like in flextable i can do something like below but looking for fixed solution or any function for DT tables.

```
(ncols %in% c(4,5)) {
    fl<-width(flxtable, width = d*0.3, j = 1)
    fl<-width(flxtable, width = (d*0.7)/(ncols-1), j = 2:ncols)
d is left and right margin of docs template
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had success with this in the past:

```
DT::datatable(df) %>%
DT::formatStyle(names(df),lineHeight='80%')
```

Kudos to the post that helped me, however I fail to find it back now.

Comment: this is still not working if the length of character gets increase then this is again the same , the height of row gets increased.

Comment: There is a price to pay. If your string is "long" and does not fit in a line, it will break. Dependent on the column width this can results in several "rows". This even applies for `flextable` - but I assume your dimensions make the heights appear to look the same. For DT I recommend to check the documentation: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html 4.4. show an example to truncate the string to make it fit into a column. The part not fitting in the column will be displayed as a tooltip. Although not a "fixed" height, you can work with the length of your string to show and column width.